# Where's the iron in Sea of Flame II?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

OrigamiRobot and I are playing through the [Sea of Flame II](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/191908-ctmcollection-vechs-super-hostile-series/#AnchorMap1), and we can't find any iron.  We got about 15 from the rotten caves, but that's not nearly enough.

Where can we find more iron?

Comment: @Kevin "...a custom map isn't a mod" [That's what I thought, too.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/34239/revisions)

Comment: More to the point, [the tag wiki agrees](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/mods/info). One could argue that in Minecraft building is part of the regular game, but maps like Vechs' are definitely giving the game another feel — so OK. Putting it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iron on the map is under the mossy citadel below the large sky shadow. The citadel is separated in three parts: the main building, the yard and the dungeons below. You pretty much have to clear the top two parts before getting to the dungeon.

Comment: Found it! :D Oh sweet iron!